# How to add some space to the left of the line numbers in linum-mode?

Tags: whitespace, linum-mode

When I enable `linum-mode` in the scratch buffer (and most other buffers I tried) there is no space to the left of the line numbers. Although when enable `linum-mode` in the `.emacs` configuration file, I get space to the left of the line numbers. Here is a picture: [image]

How can I control the format of the line numbers? I'd like at least one space to the left of the numbers (like in the `.emacs` file) in all files.

Comment: Does your `.emacs` file have more than 99 lines? If so, that would explain the extra space in the first 99 lines, but after that there is (probably) no space.

Comment: Oh snap! Yes, you’re right. I feel like an idiot haha ... Nontheless, how can I stick at least one space to the left of line numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could customize the variable [`linum-format`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers) to be a [format string](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html) that begins with a space. The simplest would be `(setq linum-format " %d")` which sticks one space in front of the formatted digit. I tried it out and it looks slightly weird:

[image]

The other thing is that if you're on Emacs 26, there is a new line number mode `display-line-numbers-mode` which is "new and improved" and has some space on the left by default:

[image]

Comment: Huh, I did try `linum-format` before posting this question and it did not work but now it is. That weirdness you see is because the numbers are no longer dynamically right aligned. The format string `"%d"` means 'take only as many spaces as you need', so even when you do `%-d`, it takes exactly as much space as it needs and the numbers look left aligned.

Comment: Also, I use Ubuntu and am on `25.2.2`, I installed Emacs using the usual `apt install`. When are they going to update Emacs in their repository, I think even Emacs 27 is out now.

Comment: i think 26.3 is the latest stable release. I'm on PureOS which gets updates from debian, and it has 26.1.  I dunno whats up with your Ubuntu :)

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade emacs` and got `emacs is already the newest version (47.0)`. Great now I don't understand the versioning. What does 47 mean if I am at 25.something. Is this your version too?

Comment: no, mine has this `emacs is already the newest version (1:26.1+1-3.2+deb10u1)`  i was quite confused about it, but found out it is a patched version of 26.1.  i do remember seeing those confusing higher version numbers on a different OS, but I'm not sure what they indicate.  you can just do `emacs --version` to get the truth

Comment: `emacs --version` was how I got `25.2.2`. Your version looks like what is on the [Debian's website](https://packages.debian.org/stable/editors/emacs). I think my emacs is not being pulled from the same repository. How can I check where is it coming from and why is it not from the Debian's repository?

Comment: i'm not sure why Ubuntu doesn't provide updated versions in its repos, but you can install newer versions from source or with a PPA like here http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/install-gnu-emacs-26-1-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-18-10/

Answer (score 0):

FWIW `(setq nlinum-format " %d")` works with `nlinum-mode` (available from your nearest GNU ELPA repository) and still right-aligns the numbers.